# Confidence Interval for predictions from Complex Survey model in R

Tags: r, prediction, glm, survey

How can I get 95% Confidence Intervals for predictions from a complex survey model generated from the *Survey* package using *svyglm()* function?

Using *prediction_summary* function from the package *prediction* gives back the needed predictions. However, no 95% CIs are produced.

How can the 95% CIs from the predictions be otained?

```
library(survey)
library(prediction)

data(api)

# Create Binary outcome
apistrat$api00_bin <- ifelse(apistrat$api00 < mean(apistrat$api00), 1, 0)


# Survey design
dstrat <- svydesign(id = ~1,strata = ~stype, weights = ~pw, data = apistrat, fpc=~fpc)


# SvyGLM model
api00bin.reg <- svyglm(api00_bin~enroll+avg.ed+yr.rnd+sch.wide, design=dstrat, family = poisson(link = "log"))


# Predictions - without 95% CIs.
prediction::prediction_summary(api00bin.reg, at = list(sch.wide = c("No", "Yes")), type = "response", level = 0.95, calculate_se = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you just use the quantile of the predictions? Is it a vector?